# A genetic disease that makes genetically and biologically male humans unable to grow facial hair (the opposite of hirsutism)

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, genetics, diseases, hair

In a live-action musical film I want to direct, *Le Président et Moi* (which means "The President and I") (I want the film to have French as its original language), there is a character named Édouard Wang. They (Wang is a closeted non-binary assigned male at birth human being) has the following physical features:

1. Despite being a 22 years old adultescent (or kidult, or young adult, or older adolescent, if you want), a genetically, and biologically male human, Wang does not have any facial hair.
2. Despite being 2.00 metres tall and weighting 160 kilograms with a banana-shaped body (they has both proportional gigantism like Hulk Hogan and massive obesity like John Candy), Édouard Wang has a raucous high-pitched voice (a raspier version of Jar Jar Binks' voice from Disney/Lucasfilm's *Star Wars*, but without saying weird words).
3. Finally, Édouard Wang is multiracial: their paternal grandfather was a Han Chinese, their paternal grandmother was a White Frenchwoman, their maternal grandfather was a Tahitian, and their maternal grandmother was a Marquesan.

So, I wonder if there is a genetic disease that makes genetically and biologically male human beings having the two physical features written at the top of the list (in other words, being a tall and obese person, but having a raspy high-pitched voice, and do not having the ability to grow sideburns, a goatee, and a moustache).

Comment: Not long enough to consider an answer. But couldn't you just handwave it and say they inherited a 'non-hairy' gene, and leave it at that? There are western AMAB that are 'hairless', so it's not that weird a concept.

Comment: Technically speaking, a genetic something-or-other that really *only* prevents male facial hair is not a "disease", but rather is a Godsend! Home run if it also reduces or eliminates general hairiness and eradicates male pattern baldness.

Comment: "Mongoloid" is a very offensive and outdated term.

Comment: @mammifereviolet4694, the use of the terms "Mongoloid" and "Caucasoid" are considered very offensive and scientifically inaccurate. As someone with the power to edit questions, I have removed these terms from your post.

Comment: You're aware that people who use they/them pronouns usually use plural verba with those pronouns, right? For this character to use the phrase "they has" is a valid choice, of course, but "they have" is vastly more common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Klinefelter syndrome](https://klinefelter.co.uk/), Syndrome de Klinefelter (AKA. "47,XXY")

A genetic disorder where the number of X chromosomes (the sex-chromosome usually paired with another X in females or a Y in males) is increased above the normal two for women and one for men. It's quite rare comprising only 4 out of 10,000 males. In men there can exist 3 Xs, and very rarely as many as 4 Xs along with a single Y chromosome.

Broader hips, a tendency to **rounder body-shape**, symptoms may also include weaker muscles, **greater height**, poor motor coordination, **less body hair**, breast growth, and less interest in sex. A normal or near-normal life expectancy is present, occasionally children may be conceived naturally, but usually only with medical intervention.

There's another condition: [Alopecia areata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alopecia_areata) ([Pelade](https://www.sante-sur-le-net.com/maladies/dermatologie/pelade/) en française). Bald-spots the size of a large coin can appear anywhere on the body/head. It's thought to occur as a stress-response in predisposed individuals. Though it doesn't spread by itself, increased stress will  increase hair-loss. May be accompanied by cicatricial alopecia, rendering the hair follicles permanently inactive due to sub-cutaneous scarring. Events such as a car-accident, bereavement and presidential crises might well be a trigger for patches to appear.

If you really want to pile-on the bad-luck, they could also suffer from [alopecia universalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alopecia_universalis) (alopécie générale - a genetic predisposition thought to be possibly triggered by exposure to some complex organic chemicals), which would render them completely hairless, anywhere on the outside of their body.

I'll leave it to the OP's discretion to decide what might suite the story best (or be able to be rhymed with).

Comment: I was thinking Klinefelter Syndrome as well but wasn't sure on the heavyset nature.  It also has the added bonus of being a genetic disease that would make someone "Intersex" which would be close to non-binary.   Please note, that most intersex people do not identify as non-binary and may even take offense that a quirk in their sex chromosomes makes them "not men."   That's not to say non-binary identification OR transgenderism do not occur, but that it should not be assumed.  If you go with Klinefelter Syndrome, you might want to establish a difference between Non-Binary and Intersex.